# Conditionally copying data depending on recurring values in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to create a new dataframe based on an existing dataframe of financial transactions but only if there are repeat values in a specific column.

For simplicity, I have `df1` with 3 columns: `'a' 'b' 'c'` and hundreds of rows. I would like to copy all rows when a value in column `b` repeats 3 or more times. In other words, if 3 or more rows have the same `b` value, I want those copied to `df2`.

I've tried

```
df2 = df1.where(df1.b.value_counts() > 2)
```

but that turns all rows to `NaN`. Rather than continue to guess and check other code I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupy()` with `np.where()`

Consider this sample:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'tag': ['a','a','a','d','e']})
>>> df
   id tag
0   1   a
1   2   a
2   3   a
3   4   d
4   5   e

>>> df['counter'] = df.groupby(['tag'])['tag'].transform('count')
>>> df
   id tag  counter
0   1   a        3
1   2   a        3
2   3   a        3
3   4   d        1
4   5   e        1

>>> df['counter'] = np.where(df['counter'] > 2, ['Retain'], ['Remove'])
>>> df
   id tag counter
0   1   a  Retain
1   2   a  Retain
2   3   a  Retain
3   4   d  Remove
4   5   e  Remove

>>> df = df[df['counter'].isin(['Retain'])]
>>> df
   id tag counter
0   1   a  Retain
1   2   a  Retain
2   3   a  Retain
```

Comment: Is there a purpose of converting to Remove or Retain?
What if I just did (using my dataset):
df1['counter'] = df1.groupby(['b'])['b'].transform('count')
df2 = df1.where(df1.counter > 2)

Comment: You can do that too. But have you tried it? Because trying it with the sample above, you'll get a `df2` with similar row count to your `df1` only that the ones that returned false in your logic of `df1.counter >2` will now be populated with `Nan` values. If you want to filter that out you'll have to use a tagger as the answer above. Or filter at `not na` values.

Comment: Ah I see why that could be a problem. Thankfully in my case I'm happy to drop the `Nan` values. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure glad to help :))

Answer (score 0):

Add a column that labels the values to keep then filter by that:

```
# Make a boolean series as a mapping of values with more than 2 counts
more_than_2_values = df1.b.value_counts() > 2
# Add a new column that indicates which values should be kept
df1["more_than_2"] = df["b"].map(more_than_2_values).fillna(False)
# Filter the data, drop the label column if desired
desired_result = df1[df1["more_than_2"].drop(columns="more_than_2"]
```